# Convert an array from Firebase to a String and display each array in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to display an array from `Firebase` into a `UITableView`. This is what I have:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    let otherVC = FriendCell()
    otherVC.usernameText?.text = friends[indexPath.row]
    print(friends[indexPath.row])

    return cell    
}
```

when I `print(friends[indexPath.row])` it displays all the users in that child properly. I am trying to get each user into their own `UITableViewCell`. I tried referencing the cell controller then get the usernameText linked with the storyboard but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bad approach. Use something like the following.

In your `TableViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var dbRef:FIRDatabaseReference!
var users = [User]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    dbRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
    startObservingDB()
}

func startObservingDB () {
    dbRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in
        var newUser = [User]()

        for user in snapshot.children {
            let userObject = User(snapshot: user as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newUser.append(userObject)
        }

        self.user = newUser
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }) { (error:Error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return users.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell
    let userRow = user[indexPath.row]

    cell.usernameLabel?.text! = userRow.username

    return cell
}
}
```

You also need a data model `User.swift`:

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseDatabase

struct User {

    var key:String!
    let itemRef:FIRDatabaseReference?
    var username:String!


    init (key:String = "",
          username:String) {

        self.key = key
        self.itemRef = nil
        self.usernam = username

    }

    init (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) {

        key = snapshot.key
        itemRef = snapshot.ref

        if let userUserName = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary, let _temporary = userUserName["username"] as? String {
            username = _temporary
        } else {
            username = ""
        }
    }

}
```